# jQuery extension and closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm learning javascript, and in the way I'm trying to learn more about jQuery. I have created a very simple "form controller" in JS, so when I create the object passing the form as parameter, it gets the events wired and hijacks the submit:

```
var FormController = function (form) {

    // private field
    var _form = $(form);
    var _url = _form.attr('action');
    var _isValid = false;

    $(form).submit(function (e) {
        submitForm();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var disableAll = function () {
        _form.find('select,input,textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    };

    var enableAll = function () {
        _form.find('select,input,textarea').removeAttr('disabled')
    };

    var submitForm = function () {

        disableAll();
        _isValid = true;

        if (_isValid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: _url,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    enableAll();
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    print(data.Result ? data.Result : "[No Result]");
                    print(textStatus.toString());
                },
                error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    print(textStatus);
                    _form.css('border', '1px solid Red');
                    enableAll();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // public fields and functions
    return {
        getIsValid: function () { return _isValid; },
        submit: function () { return submitForm(); }
    };
};
```

It works as expected. Now I would like to create a jQuery extension, so I can apply that object to the results:

```
$.fn.formController = function () {
    return this.each(function (i, item) {
        new FormController(item);
    });
};
```

I also works as expected, but... will the GC collect that object? Or because the events are wired, it counts as referenced?

Now, I would like to keep the instances of my controllers available, so I can manipulate them after creation, for example for invoking methods. Something like this:

```
$('#myForm').formController('submit');
```

I have tried several ways to do it, but I cannot get it. I have tried to put a closure with a object that keep track of the items, etc... but I just got mess with "this".

What would be the correct way to do this? And I assume that everything I have done so far could be wrong even if it works.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Sorry if the question was not clear enough. What I am aiming for is a way I can do : `$('#myForm').formController('submit');` , and then the funcion will find the "FormController" object associated with that HTML object, and invoke this "submit" member.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
$.fn.formController = function (name) {

    if(!document._items)
        document._items = [];

    if (name) {
        return this.each(function (i, item) {
            var id = $(item).data('form-controller');

            if (id) {
                var fc = document._items[id];
                var member = fc[name];
                if (member) {
                    if (typeof member == 'function')
                        member();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {    
        return this.each(function (i, item) {
            var id = document._items.push(new FormController(item)) - 1;
            $(item).data('form-controller', id.toString());
        });
    }
};
```

The problem in this approach is that I'm keeping a collection as global object, and what I want is make it internal. I have tried with a closure, but I only got into problems with "this" (that points to DOMwindow), or the "_items" var being empty.

What would be the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI's Widget factory, which gives you that functionality out-of-the-box:

```
$.widget("vtortola.formcontroller", {
    _create: function() {
         // Use `this.element` to initialize the element.
         // You can also use this.options to get the options object that was passed.
    },
    _destroy: function() {
        // You can unbind events here to remove references from the DOM, so is'll get
        // deleted by the garbage collector.
    },
    submit: function() { /* ... */ }
});

// Example
$('#form').formcontroller({foo: 123}); // Calls `_create()` with the supplied options
$('#form').formcontroller('submit'); // Calls the `submit` method
```

The widget factory also gives you options setter/getters, default options, and other cool stuff. See [the official docs](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) and the [tutorial at bililite](http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/) for more details. If you aren't using jQuery UI for other stuff, you can use the [widget factory code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js) as a stand-alone, its not depended on other parts of jQuery UI.

If you prefer to it without using jQuery UI's widget factory, you can store the objects directly on `.data()` (which is also what the widget factory does), no need to keep a collection of them and keep track of that manually. Your code would be something along the lines of:

```
$.fn.formController = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.each(function (i, item) {
        var $this = $(this), _obj;
        // When calling `$(..)`.formController() with arguments when the object already
        // exists, it treats the first argument as the method name and passes the rest
        // as arguments to that method.
        if (arguments.length && (_obj = $this.data('FormController'))) {
            _obj[args[0]].apply(_obj, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
        } else {
            $this.data('FormController', new FormController(item));
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The second example does not work, first because there is a typo in "FromController" :D But also because "arguments[0]" is always "0", it does not contain the 'submit' term. Any idea about why is this happening?

Comment: Oh, `arguments` there refers to the arguments passed to the `each()` function. I updated the code to fix that.

Comment: Updated the code again, it was missing a namespace for the widget name

Comment: It works great! Thanks a million. this example will help me to understand better js an jQuery, and start to doing my own extensions. Thanks again :)

Comment: I have to wait till tomorrow to grant you the bounty :P

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad to help. I highly recommended you to try and write your extension as widgets, its provides a great infrastructure for OOP code and gives you many common utilities that can make development much faster.

Comment: Ah by the way, do you know how the GC will cope with objects that are wired to events? In this specific scenario, what conditions should be given to allow the GC collect a FormController objec?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
(function($){
    $.fn.formController = function(parameter1, parameter2){
            //this = #myForm
    }
)(jQuery);
```

and read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Ma)

Comment: Well, what I am interested is in the inside of the method, I got there by myself :D I wanna know how to create a closure with an array inside that method for example, or another technique to achieve what I want.

Comment: @vtortola: I did not get you, what are you trying to do inside?

Comment: Ok, as you can see I create an object "FormController" when I call to "$('#theForm').formController()". What I want is a way to call methods from that object afterwards. For example, "$('#theForm').formController('submit')". For that, I need to keep internally a hash table with all instances of "FormController", but I don't know what I can use has key, and I don't know where to put the collection, or how to do it.

Comment: @vtortola: I did post a code for you, it does exactly you need! `this` refers to #theForm

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the instance of FormController I created before from the form object?

Comment: I have update the question, sorry if it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried creating a collection as property of the function itself.

It works, but I don't know how correct/appropriate it is :D

```
$.fn.formController = function (name) {

    if (name) {
        return this.each(function (i, item) {
            var id = $(item).data('form-controller');

            if (id) {
                var fc = $.fn.formController.Items[id];
                print('get: ' + id + ' ' + (fc?'found':'not found'));
                var member = fc[name];
                if (member) {
                    if (typeof member == 'function')
                        member();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {

        return this.each(function (i, item) {
            var id = $.fn.formController.Items.push(new FormController(item)) - 1;
            print('add: ' + id);
            $(item).data('form-controller', id.toString());
        });
    }
};
$.fn.formController.Items = [];
```